# Show that $EX_1 1_A \geq 0$ given A is an event $\left(\sum\limits_1^n X_i>0 \right)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, expectation, independence

Let A be the event

$\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i>0 \right)$ where $\{X_i\}_{i = 1, 2, ..., n}$ is an independent and identically distributed collection of random variables

Show that $E[X_1 \mathbb{1}_A] \geq 0$

Previous part:

the first two parts of the question which I solved were to show how two probabilities agree on a Pi-system agree on the sigma-algebra it generates and a sequence of i.i.d random variables's joint distribution are equal no matter what permutation it is in. Not sure if this helps

Comment: Hint: $E(X_1\mathbf 1_A)=E(X_k\mathbf 1_A)$ for every $k$ and $\sum\limits_kE(X_k\mathbf 1_A)=E((X_1+\cdots+X_n)\mathbf 1_A)$ hence ...

Comment: Thanks Did again, but may I know how does the indicator function relate to the event?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

Comment: adding from your comment: Since $X_1+...+X_n$ larger than 0 we get $E[(X_1+..+X_n)1_A]\geq0$ ? is that right?

Comment: @YauKinHoe $\sum_n X_n$ is not always $> 0$ but I think the conclusion is true anyway by monotonicity

Comment: @YauKinHoe Yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Since $X_1, \dots, X_n$'s are iid,

$$E[X_1 1_A] = E[X_k 1_A] \ \forall 1 \le k \le n$$

$$\to \sum_k E[X_k 1_A] = \sum_k E[X_1 1_A] = nE[X_1 1_A]$$

Also, $$\sum_k E[X_k 1_A] = E[(\sum_k X_k) 1_A] = \int_A \sum_k X_k dP$$

Now $$\int_A \sum_k X_k dP > 0$$

by applying monotonicity of integration on $$(\sum_k X_k)1_A > 0$$

Comment: You could have the decency to CW this.